# Rebuild of fulltext catalog is very slow

Tags: sql-server, full-text-catalog

I have recently added iFilters to my SQL Server and configured a FullText catalog to index a blob column on a database with 1.4 mil records. The SQL server is running in a production environment with a lot of load, but mostly during daytime.

The first 600K was indexed somewhat speedy, but now the index speed is down to around 10K records per day leaving me with a time to complete index at around 50 days from today..!

We did not monitor the initial indexing, before adding iFilters, but we assume that the performance issue was introduced by adding PDF iFilters, but we can not be certain.

Is there anyway to speed up the indexing at night time, or any important settings I might have missed? It seems like a bit of a black box to me. I have found very little on ways of tweaking index settings.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Full text catalogs are vastly different from 2005 to 2008+.

Comment: What are results of following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142560.aspx ?

Comment: @Reaces: I will have to check, but definately 2008R2 minimum.

Comment: @Brian: My assumption is that it is iFilter related, because it was not until iFilters were activated that indexing run so slow as this. I can see the bottom tip in particular is about this. Can I see anywhere if errors in the threading model are the cause of the performance problems?